# Styles from a github css file

Tags: css, github

Can I use a styles.css file uploaded on GitHub as styles for multiple projects? I'm trying to define a default style for my projects here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GhitaB/default-design/master/styles.css

I prefer to link this file instead of copying it in multiple projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) serves raw files directly from GitHub with proper Content-Type headers.

Or, consider using [Github Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/)

Comment: It's working for me with tags. I generate a new tag for each change in my default styles then I update the RawGit cdn link in my projects to use the new tag. That solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to distinguish between duplication of code and resources. What you don't want is copying code, because those files would diverge and you'd need to repeat every change for all of them. Having one file uploaded to multiple servers, however, shouldn't be a problem as long as you have one place to edit them all at once.

For this case there's Git submodules. The idea is basically having a repository with the shared part and then including that repository in a specified path in your other projects. You can read more about it here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

This way all your IDE-based and external tools will still work and your website can be deployed as a whole. If, at some point in the future, you decide to have separate CSS files, you can simply replace the submodule with a file and you won't need to change the paths in HTML.

---

Of course, you can also use the same exact resource in multiple projects simply by pointing them to the same URI, but then the uncoupling might be harder afterwards and you can't see the file in your IDE.